# Tomcat is web server or application server?

Tags: tomcat, webserver, application-server, servlet-container

Is Tomcat a web server or an application server?

Comment: @Suresh You may find better results on http://serverfault.com (Stack Overflow's Server-Question Website).

Comment: this is not for server-fault, it is a theoretical development related question.

Comment: Before posting any question. do add/show some research efforts. Additionally try to briefly explain your question.

Comment: Coming from IBM: [Apache Tomcat](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/web-server-vs-application-server)
is an open source **application server** that executes Java Servlets, renders and delivers web pages that include JavaServer Page code, and serves Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE) applications. Released in 1998, Tomcat is the most widely used open source Java **application server**.

Answer (score 62):

Tomcat is a [web server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) (can handle HTTP requests/responses) and [web container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) (implements [Java Servlet API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340), also called servletcontainer) in one. Some may call it an [application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server), but it is definitely not an fullfledged Java EE application server (it does not implement [the whole Java EE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/overview-summary.html)).

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee/)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading/)

Comment: It is not "technically incorrect".

Tomcat and Jetty are application servers.  Specifically they are web application servers.  They are not Java EE (or J2EE) application servers, but they are application servers in the generic sense of the term.

Comment: Makes sense from that point of view. But I'd generally avoid this term for starters. Tomcat is a webcontainer (also called servletcontainer) and that's generally clear enough.

Comment: Wait for Java EE 6 profiles and they will officially be JEE application server :)

Comment: Wait?  Glassfish is already Java EE 6 compliant.

Comment: so tomcat is web server and apache is also web server so it means i am using two web server ?

Comment: @Mahi: "Apache" is the name of a software company.

Comment: i mean *apache web server.

Answer (score 14):

Tomcat is an application container that is also a web server. An application container can run web-applications (have "application" scope). <strike>It is not considered</strike> Some people do not consider it a full application server as it is lacking in some aspects such as user management and the like, but getting better all the time..

Comment: @Nir it seems contradictory if tomcat can do 100% what web server does, then it should fall under a part application server

Comment: You cannot deploy EAR files to Tomcat.  That makes it a non-application server.

Comment: @Andersen - but you can deply war.

Comment: @Andersen - can u deploy war file in apache http web server (which i think so?)

Comment: Who states that you need to be able to deploy an EAR for something to qualify as an "application server"?

Comment: @Suresh - if you mean httpd, then no you can't deploy WAR files to it.

Comment: A "web server" is something that can serve web pages (static & dynamic) and tomcat does that so it's a web server. An application server is something that runs applications and tomcat does that so it's also an application server. However, some would say it's not complete application server as it lacks some features that other application servers have, so the term "application container" is more suited imho.

Comment: @Suresh also please understand that Tomcat server and Apache server are two different things. As Tomcat is part of the Apache Foundation it is something called "Apache Tomcat" which is confusing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat vs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen if tomcat would be non-application server(web server) then it wouldn't handle servlet but it does . so i think it is 50%

Comment: Tomcat does not implement the full profiles necessary for it to be called an Application Server under what is defines in the related JSRs, But so many people use it for serving applications that it is commonly refered to as an application server

Answer (score 10):

Tomcat is a web server and a Servlet/JavaServer Pages container.  It is often used as an application server for strictly web-based applications but does not include the entire suite of capabilities that a Java EE application server would supply.

Links:

- [Apache Tomcat home page](http://tomcat.apache.org/)
- [Explanation of Servlet technology](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/index.jsp)
- [Explanation of JavaServer Pages technology](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/)

Answer (score 6):

> Apache Tomcat is an open source
>   software implementation of the Java
>   Servlet and JavaServer Pages
>   technologies.

Since Tomcat does not implement the full Java EE specification for an application server, it can be considered as a **web server**.

*Source: http://tomcat.apache.org*

Answer (score 4):

Application Server:

Application server maintains the application logic and
serves the web pages in response to user request.

That means application server can do both application logic 
maintanence and web page serving.

Web Server:

Web server just serves the web pages and it cannot enforce 
any application logic.

Final conclusion is: Application server also contains the 
web server.

For further Reference : 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-08/01-qa-0823-appvswebserver.html

Comment: Additionally, Web server in Application server is called "reverse proxy" and it supports for load-balancing and responding static contents.

Answer (score 0):

It runs Java compiled code, it can maintain database connection pools, it can log errors of various types.  I'd call it an application server, in fact I do.  In our environment we have Apache as the webserver fronting a number of different application servers, including Tomcat and Coldfusion, and others.