# How to play video in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to play a mp4 video on my HTML page, I have searched the web and found that in HTML5 I can do this with `video` tag like this below

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Issue I am facing**

- My main issue is my video is stored in my local computer in some location, So how can I call that from that path
- In my system it is located in `D drive` so I want to call it from there
- I am new to this so I don't know if I am doing it the right way; is my approach correct?
- My requirement is to auto-play video on my web page

I am doing like this

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="D:\Video\samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

`D:\Video\samplevideo.mp4` is the path of my file and `samplevideo.mp4` is the name of the video

On Chrome it show error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4`

And on Firefox `All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.`

### Edit

My main focus is to play video on webpage.

I need to play a video on the web (HTML page) when page is loaded I have that video in my system at `D:\Video\samplevideo.mp4` this path, how can I play that video when page is loaded.

[image: Console image]

Comment: Does your video load properly? See your browser console for any errors.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag

Comment: @randomSoul no it is not loading it shows error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4` on crome and on fire fox    `All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.`

Comment: use file:///D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4 or host on a webserver and give the url

Comment: @DevsiOdedra that one i have already seen it is about to select video from local drive then play

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007243/cannot-open-local-file-chrome-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource

Comment: @PDKPavanKumar hey that is not working, and i am doing this project on local server using tomcat so no way to host it on webserver i have to call that file from local system,on which system this page is loaded

Comment: @manishthakur why are there 3 slashes instead of 2?

Comment: @xmaster i am doing it like `<source src="file://D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">` please check my edit i have uploaded console image

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser)

Comment: "local server using tomcat so no way to host it on webserver" - [Tomcat is a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469949/tomcat-is-web-server-or-application-server). What are you entering into your browser address bar to view the page?

Comment: @JonP `http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/test.html` this is my URL to open Page, I think i am doing it wrong way if you can help me with some approach or guidance it will be very helpful

Comment: @xmaster that is something else to what i am trying to do

Comment: In general **you can't play local content**, that is the error you are getting. This is a security issue. A web server should have no information about the users (clients) file system, again a very important security measure. How does your server know the client has a  file at that location? You may do, but another user may not even have a `D` drive, let alone a `D` drive with a *video* directory.

Comment: yup now i get that, I have to put the video in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code

```
 <video muted autoplay loop class="video video js-video" id="hero-vid" poster="video/desktop-screen-banner.png">
    <source src="video/movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: hey i am doing same my main issue is the video file is in my local pc so what should i put in place of `src="movie.mp4"`, can you explain me where that movie.mp4 file is ?

Comment: Make the Video Folder. video is required in 3 formats 
1.) webm
2.) mp4
3.) ogg

Comment: I have already made a video folder which is in my PC not in my project and i can play any one of them on my web page no need to have all three format

Comment: once you try the relative path.

Comment: You are saying to create a video folder in my project and put that video inside that?

Comment: But i cant create a folder inside my project directory because when in future if user want to change the video then i need to go to my code, that's why i am trying to create a folder in my local system

Comment: Then there is no other option. 
If you upload any video player like youtube or Vimeo then you should have to change link either you should change local video in the folder.

Comment: Local Video means you should play without uploading. You can play your local pc video in a webpage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193980/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-riddhi-busa).

Comment: It is not working on crome as i am using all 3 formats

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some pieces of advice.First,you can use the absolute path about video,place the video file on the server,then you can get a path such as `www.xxx.com/movie.mp4`,and you can write the code on your `HTML page`,like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="www.xxx.com/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Second,you can place your video file on the directory as same as the HTML page location.For example,if your HTML page in the directory which called `test`.you can create a directory which called `src`,and you can write the code on your `HTML page`,like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="./src/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Third,you can use the `input` tag to upload the local video file,the `HTML` code as below:

```
  <input type="file" id="myInput"/>
  <video controls autoplay></video>
```

the `js` code as below:

```
     var input = document.getElementById('myInput'), 
         video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            video.innerHTML = '<source src="' + url + '" type="video/mp4">';
        }
```

Fourth,use the `object` tag.you can write the code,like this:

```
//the HTML code
<div id="playhere"></div>
```

```
//js code
function play(fn){
  var str='<object id="MediaPlayer" height="300" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="width:70%"><param name="URL" value=\''+fn+'\'\/><param name="autoStart" value="1"\/><param name="balance" value="0"\/><param name="baseURL" value=""\/><param name="currentPosition" value="0"\/><param name="currentMarker" value="0"\/><param name="defaultFrame" value=""\/><param name="enabled" value="1"\/><param name="enableErrorDialogs" value="0"\/><param name="enableContextMenu" value="0"\/><param name="fullScreen" value="0"\/><param name="invokeURLs" value="1"\/><param name="mute" value="0"\/><param name="playCount" value="1"\/><param name="rate" value="1"\/><param name="stretchToFit" value="0"\/><param name="uiMode" value="full"\/><param name="volume" value="100"\/><param name="windowlessVideo" value="1"\/><\/object>';
   document.getElementById('playhere').innerHTML=str;
}
// that's your video file location
 play('D:\\Video\\samplevideo.mp4')
```

but that way isn't supported on chrome browser.

Excuse me,I'm new to speak English.

Comment: hey your answer is suggesting to upload the video first, here i have a video in my system (PC) i need to play that

Comment: My fourth advice can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try this**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also follow this link for more info.

http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-and-play-videos-in-html/26171

Comment: yes i am doing the same but my video file is in my local computer not in my project so what should i put at sre="movie.mp4"

Comment: you can add the proper path .

Comment: 1. Right click on the video file. then go to properties

Comment: 2. Then you can take the location of the file . And add them in to your src=" " hare.

Comment: please check this reference  http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-and-play-videos-in-html/26171  . hope this will help you.

Comment: @manishthakur  how  you are rendering this file ? simply making a one html file and then  double clcikcking this file or running this file with any web server like xamp or wamp?

Comment: @NeerajAmoli I am using Tomcat

Comment: @manishthakur upload your video inside that folder where html file is ,and then try to give name of video to src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For the very basics of getting this working move `D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4` to the same location as your html file.

Then change your code to:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Make sure Tomcat is set up to server the `.mp4` mimetype or extention.

Next you should read up on how paths work in HTML.

Comment: That video i can't move to my HTML location i need to call this from a file/ folder only as it will be dynamic user will be changing the videos as per there requirement

Comment: Note the error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Video/samplevideo.mp4`  - You are not allowed to load local resources. The user will not be able to play video on their machine on a page served by your (tomcat) webserver. How is the user choosing otherwise dynamically generating the video.  Please expand on your question as I suspect you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score -1):

you need to put an alternative text like this to check of your browser or smartphone supports video autoplay.

like this:

````
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

```
````

Comment: hey i am doing this same i thing you are copying paste answer from google

Comment: Also try to use this syntax for an alternative:

`<video width="320" height="240" controls>`