# Add a video from a website via the google chrome console

Tags: html

On a website (who is not mine), in the console Google Chrome, I would like to create a `div` and into this div, I would like to add a video which is on my desktop.

I don't understand why my video is not displayed? I think it's a problem concerning the way?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="../FR-V2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play video in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320362/how-to-play-video-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video source will need to be an absolute path linking to the video folder path.

`../FR-V2.mp4` - will need to be direct (for displaying via console)

`C://Users/user/desktop/website/videos/FR-V2.mp4`